# angular js files are not loaading in rails application

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created an application in rails , i have written small angular example ,  I have written in partial file and rendered it. But nothing is loading. Will angular work in partials? my code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.products = ["Milk", "Bread", "Cheese"];
});
</script>

<div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in products">{{x}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<p>So far we have made an HTML list based on the items of an array.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

And the output is

```
{{x}}
So far we have made an HTML list based on the items of an array.
```

And i am not getting any error in console or firebug
Can anybody suggest solution

Comment: there isn't a problem loading angular into rails views and I was able to run your example. Could you specify where and how you're calling the partial?

Comment: i kept this code in a partial file , based on the menu item selected the partial will be rendered. i am redering the partial like this                        <%= render :partial => "reports/sales_report"%>

Comment: this seems o.k. have you checked the devtools console for js errors?

Comment: Ya . No issue. And i am using Angular 1.3.14 and jquery 3.1.4 Is that an issue? Or redering in partial will it make difference?

Comment: I'm not aware of such an incompatibility issue. Either way, rendering the partial is not your problem - I copy-pasted the code above into a partial in a test rails project and rendered it successfully into a view. I assume you're not using IE8 or less?

Comment: are the div and script tags there when you look at the source in the browser? Could you be using strip_tags or sanitize on the response object?

Comment: Ya my script file is loading in the browser but not reflecting in the view . No i am not using strip_tags or sanitize .

Comment: I am getting Empty string passed to getElementById(). in jquery file will this effect?

Comment: please add the code where getElementById is called

Comment: I think it is not the issue, is there any combination of angular and jquery versions to work with? is there any chance some jquery files overwriting my angular controller?

Comment: you said earlier that you use angular 1.3.14, but the sample code in the question imports version 1.4.8. I used the sample code, meaning 1.4.8, with both jQuery 1.2.14 and 3.1.1, and both worked fine. I'm not aware of a jQuery 3.1.4 version.

Comment: I have solved the issue by manual bootstrap adding this lines 
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])
    In my code.

Comment: Every thing is working fine when i load the file for the first time  but when i reload the file i am having same issue can anybody help?